# How to access ext variables in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, crashlytics

I am trying to get the variable defined in a 3rd party library (fabric) to do a condition based on whether Crashlytics is enabled or not.

```
ext.enableCrashlytics = true
```

http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202938-gradle
The variable can be configured in buildTypes or in flavors but I can't find a way to access it elsewhere in my build.gradle

I tried several things without any luck.

```
allprojects.getProperties().get("enableCrashlytics")
project.enableCrashlytics
project.ext.enableCrashlytics
allProjects.ext.enableCrashlytics
```

Anyone tried that before? The context I'm trying to do this is to write the fabric.properties file based on if it is enabled or not.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  ...
  //create fabric.properties
  ...
}
```

Comment: *variable defined in a 3rd party library* How is the variable defined in the library? Is it a gradle script that you're using with `apply from:` in your build script?

Comment: It's something in Crashlytic's build.gradle I would guess because that's how to disable it from their website!

Answer (score 18):

You can define a property in your top-level `build.gradle`:

```
ext {
  myproperty = 12
}
```

Or an array:

```
ext {

    myarray = [
            name0     : "xx",
            name1     : "xx"
   ]
}
```

Then in each module you can use somenthig like:

```
rootProject.ext.myproperty
rootProject.ext.myarray.name0
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that syntax too but the problem is that I'm not the one defining the variable I just enable or disable the flag but the variable is defined in their build.gradle I would guess!? If I try accessing it with rootProject.ext.enableCrashlytics it gives the following error "Error:(272, 0) Cannot get property 'enableCrashlytics' on extra properties extension as it does not exist"

Comment: You should define ext.enableCrashlytics in your top-level build.gradle.
With crashlitycs you are importing a dependency (aar) which can't contain a gradle file.

Comment: Ok, defining it in the top level build.gradle, I can print the value using println "enableCrashlytics: " + variant.name.capitalize() + " :: " + rootProject.ext.enableCrashlytics although it just won't care if one flavor is disabling it. It prints true for every variants even if I set one of the flavor to ext.enableCrashlytics = false. Am I missing someting?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I stumbled upon it while attempting to do a similar thing.

After trial and error and reading through the build system source I figured it out.

```
variants.all { variant ->
     println("${variant.name.capitalize()}")
     println(variant.getBuildType().myFoo)
     println("------")
}
```

With this you'll be able to read the ExtraPropertiesExtensions from the different variants.

My output:

```
Debug
true
------
Release
true
------
Something
false
------
```

Here are the files I looked through to figure it out:
[ApplicationVariantImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/6d7fd0d2eff092abf1aaf44d03756b24570b390c/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/api/ApplicationVariantImpl.java) and [DefaultBuildType](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/e42f95730119a5440acea0ccd9a18f17a09b365f/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/DefaultBuildType.java)

Answer (score 0):

`project.hasProperty 'propName'`
  (parens optional when possible in groovy, prefer 'String' over "GString")