# Nested dynamic properties in gradle scripts?

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to use nested properties in gradle build scripts to group global variables?

if `gradle.properties` file contains

```
mavenUpload.serverUrl=https://someServer.org/mavenrepository
```

can i use this in gradle scripts like this `${mavenUpload.serverUrl}` or like this?

```
// in master gradle.build
task uploadArchives {
    description = "Upload to maven repository '${mavenUpload.serverUrl}'."

    // call all uploadArchives in the sub projects
    dependsOn { subprojects.uploadArchives }
}
```

Is it even possible to dynamically create nested properties like this

```
ext {
    mavenUpload {
        serverUrl='https://someServer.org/mavenrepository'
        login='myUsername'
        password='myTopSecretPassword'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar to this in gradle?

My current workaround is to use an underscore "_" instead of a point "."

What i have tried in gradle 2.13

```
ext {
    // works as expected
    myglobal='my global value'

    // error :-(
    myGlobalNested1 {
        myNested='my nested value'
    }

    // error :-(
    myGlobalNested2.ext {
        myNested='my nested value'
    }

    // error :-(
    myGlobalNested4.ext.myNested='my nested value'

    // error :-(
    myGlobalNested5.myNested='my nested value'

    myGlobalNested3 = new HashMap<String,Object>()      

}

// error :-(
myGlobalNested3.ext.myNested='my nested value'

task demo {
    // works as expected
    ext.mylocal='my local value'

    print """
        myglobal = ${myglobal}
        mylocal = ${mylocal}
        demo.mylocal = ${demo.mylocal}

        myGlobalNested.myNested = ${myGlobalNested.myNested}
    """
}
```

[Update 2016-06-11 @opal]

This script does not compile. The parts with `// error :-(` cause a compile error

Comment: For me the question is unclear a bit. Could you please provide a single example of a _desired_ script thats is not working?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend using `ext` inside another one. That would result some very weird behaviors from gradle. The top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635272/how-to-access-ext-variables-in-gradle) gives us the right way of creating nested ext variables.

This would be the right way of making nested variables in gradle

```
ext {
    myarray = [
            name0     : "xx",
            name1     : "xx"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also struggling with the same problem...

How is this?

```
ext {
    parent = ext {
        child = ext {
            grandChild = ext {
                greatGrandChild = "Kourtney"
            }
            grandChildBrother = "Khloé"
        }
        childSister = "Kim"
    }
}
```

and then

```
task demo {
    print """
            child sister is ${this.ext.parent.childSister}
            grand child brother is ${this.ext.parent.child.grandChildBrother}
            great grand child is 
            ${this.ext.parent.child.grandChild.greatGrandChild}
    """
}
```

Good luck!